# Why don't my small_words() and large_words() function work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to eliminate all the words shorter than 3 characters and longer than 7 characters but my functions don't seem to work

```
import random
import sys

word_list = ['zebra',  'memory', 'desktop', 'earthquake', 
'infinity','marker', 'chocolate', 'school', 'microwave', 
'microphone', 'battle','battery', 'gorilla', 'memory', 'calendar', 
'plant', 'pants', 'trophy','pollution', 'carpenter', 'son', 'join']

guess_word = []
secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
lenght_word = len(secret_word)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
letter_storage = []

def main():
    small_words()
    large_words()

def small_words():
    global word_list
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word) <= 3:
            word_list.remove(word)

def large_words():
    global word_list
    for words in word_list:
        if len(words) > 7:
            word_list.remove(words)
```

Comment: Where you are calling `main` function?.

Comment: in python it is better to create new list with elements which you want to keep because when you remove element from list then all elements change positions in list (they "move left") and `for-loop` doesn't know it  so `for-loop` skips next element after deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are modifying the list as you are iterating it, which is almost always a bad idea. This will cause the loop to skip values every time you delete something from it.

The way to do this in python is to use a list comprehension. It's short enough you don't really need a function:

```
word_list = [word for word in word_list if len(word) > 3 ]
word_list = [word for word in word_list if len(word) <= 7]
```

or together in one:

```
word_list = [word for word in word_list if 3 < len(word) <= 7]
```

An alternative is to use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

```
word_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3 and len(x) <= 7, word_list))
```

Using the filter method, you can take a function and a sequence as arguments, which returns an iterable, only yielding the items in the sequence for which the function returns True. In this specific case, since you only want words of length strictly greater than 3 and no more than 7, you can define a lambda function that does the job together with the filter method.

Comment: short but it would need explanation to make it sweet  for beginner.